# How do I use lots I've downloaded on TSR?

Tags: the-sims

I've downloaded so many lots to use from TSR but I cannot figure out how to use any of them! Help please?

Comment: What is TSR? I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: @Aaron128l A google search shows a website where you can download all kind of custom stuff for The Sims.

Comment: Could you clarify which version of The Sims you are using? I believe TSR has (or had) lots for versions 2 through 4, and the procedure is bound to be different for each.

Answer (score 3):

Downloaded Sims and Lots

Downloaded Sims and Lots contain each several files. All the downloaded files for that creation need to be placed in the Sims 4 Tray folder. The location of that folder is:

Documents/Electronic Arts/The Sims 4/Tray

You must unzip the file and place only the tray items in your tray, not the zip file.

Once you have placed them there, you should be able to find the Sims or Lots in your personal Gallery in the game.

More info [here](http://www.thesimsresource.com/helpcenter/view-post/post/26847/Installing%20The%20Sims%204%20Downloads)

Comment: @Aaron128l That's google black belt right there